# javascript ajax onchange select box while doing update

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onchange

I have a select box which populates data based on selection on other select boxes.

I am able to populate data. But how to make a value selected and do `onchange` event during editing of the form. ie, updation.

I am facing difficulty in making it selected based on database entry and to do `onchange`. What I am able to do it just the populating data from DB based on change.

Comment: Please show your code otherwise we cannot help you - see how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

you can easly create it with jquery, here's the example:

```
$('#id_of_your_select').change(function(){
    var val = $('#id_of_your_select option').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $.post({
        url: "your_url",
        data: {
            value: val; // get the input post of value in server side
        },
        success: function(result){
        // loop a json array and use append function of the jquery on the second select box
        }
    })
});
```

i can only explain like that cause there's no code that you give.

Comment: I want to create an update page which will have this selected data populated